# Conditionally ignore parameter in Terraform if its value is not provided?

Tags: terraform, google-cloud-sql, terraform-provider-gcp

I am using [*"google_sql_database_instance"*](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/google/r/sql_database_instance.html) resource to create a cloud instance with private IP only and taking the value for [_private_network_](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/google/r/sql_database_instance.html#private_network) from variables file or command line argument or no value provided at all.

All I am trying to achieve is, create private IP instance only if *private_network* is provided and include [_private_network_](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/google/r/sql_database_instance.html#private_network) parameter *only* if its value is provided. The problem here is this variable doesn't accept empty string (*""*) as it validates the bellow regular expression. 
`"projects/((?:(?:[-a-z0-9]{1,63}\\.)*(?:[a-z](?:[-a-z0-9]{0,61}[a-z0-9])?):)?(?:[0-9]{1,19}|(?:[a-z0-9](?:[-a-z0-9]{0,61}[a-z0-9])?)))/global/networks/((?:[a-z](?:[-a-z0-9]*[a-z0-9])?))$"`.

How would I make a module which is configurable (create private IP instance only if *private_network* is provided otherwise ignore the parameter completely) and does not compulsorily asks for the value of [_private_network_](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/google/r/sql_database_instance.html#private_network) variable?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The old approach to this would be to pass an empty string (`""`) to the parameter and the provider would ignore it by convention.

Unfortunately this isn't done everywhere across all providers yet so if you are unable to pass an empty string due to validation on the parameter then you're stuck for now.

The options you have are to [raise a pull request for the provider](https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-google) allowing you to pass an empty string, create a second module that differs only by whether it has a private network, or wait for Terraform 0.12 which will [introduce the `null` value](https://www.hashicorp.com/blog/terraform-0-12-conditional-operator-improvements#conditionally-omitted-arguments) that will then make Terraform core ignore the parameter entirely.

The last option is the best one in my opinion but if you have an urgent need (currently no expected release date for 0.12 other than when it's ready) then I'd split the module into two for now to get you able to achieve this and then you can drop the private clone of the module and use the `null` value when 0.12 is released and you have upgraded to it.